# Channel returns the same value twice on receive

Tags: go, concurrency, range, channel, goroutine

Hello I have the following simple program:
I have a function `printNums(nums chan int)` which should take 3 numbers from a channel and print them concurrently. Each printing is done in a new goroutine inside the range statement.
However when I run this program, instead of expected output `4, 12, 32`, i get `12, 12, 32`. Can you help me find out where is the problem and why i don't receive from channel same values that have been sent to channel? Thank you.

```
package main

import ("fmt")

func printNums(nums chan int){
    c := make(chan struct{}, 100)
        for num := range(nums){
            go func(){
                fmt.Println(num)
                c <- struct{}{}
            }()
        }
    <-c
    <-c
    <-c
}
func main(){
    nums := make(chan int)

  go func() {
      nums <- 4
      nums <- 12 
      nums <- 32 
      close(nums)
  }()

  printNums(nums)
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `c` channel is a makeshift waitgroup https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the current value of `num` instead of the value `num` was when the goroutine was created. The loop variable is overwritten at every turn, and the goroutine may see the updated value.

```
for num := range(nums){
    go func(x int){
         fmt.Println(x)
         c <- struct{}{}
    }(num)
 }
```